# Image gallery with a Lightbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox, gallery

I'd like to create a jQuery image gallery of showcased products. It will show one product image at a time, with Next/Previous arrows, and a brief name and price as overlay on the image. If users click it, it will go to the order page. It will have an icon to show a larger, modal version (Lightbox style) of the image with full description, price, and a link to a page to order it.

In other words, it's an inline gallery, about 250px X 150px, with next/previous option, but also with a little icon to fire it up in a lightbox type modal window that can have links.

Here's an [example](http://fancybox.net/) which doesn't have the inline gallery effect. Here's [another](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html), also missing the inline gallery. Is there such a beast as what I'm looking for? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like fancybox does exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks, bschaeffer. I looked at it and now will see how to implement it on the page. I like all the different options it provides.

Comment: @bschaeffer - Please turn this into an answer with a link to it so I can upvote and close this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this, maybe you find it useful for your project: https://github.com/creotiv/jquery-photowall